# Display different csv files in tabs using tkinter

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I want to display  multiple csv files (3 at least) **in the same** tkinter window but I have no clue how to do it. I have only found codes to display a single file in a window.

My current level in python is quite low (I'm a healthcare professional trying to do basic stuff) and it's basically adding together some code found online here and there but I still understand simple functions such as buttons and windows.

I have uploaded a picture to show more accurately what I'm aiming for: [My goal in tkinter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJW27.png)

Here is my current and my attempts so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import Frame
import csv


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Python - Healthcare continuity")
width = 500
height = 400
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width / 2) - (width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (height / 2)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
root.resizable(0, 0)

TableMargin = ttk.Frame(root)
TableMargin.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

scrollbarx = Scrollbar(TableMargin, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scrollbary = Scrollbar(TableMargin, orient=VERTICAL)

# open file
with open("open(first.csv,'r+',encoding='utf-8')", newline = "") as file:
   reader = csv.reader(file)

   # r and c tell us where to grid the labels
   r = 0
   for col in reader:
      c = 0
      for row in col:
         # i've added some styling
         label = tkinter.Label(root, width = 10, height = 2, \
                               text = row, relief = tkinter.RIDGE)
         label.grid(row = r, column = c)
         c += 1
      r += 1

with open("second.csv", newline = "") as file:
   reader = csv.reader(file)

   # r and c tell us where to grid the labels
   r = 0
   for col in reader:
      c = 0
      for row in col:
         # i've added some styling
         label = tkinter.Label(root, width = 10, height = 2, \
                               text = row, relief = tkinter.RIDGE)
         label.grid(row = r, column = c)
         c += 1
      r += 1

with open("third.csv", newline = "") as file:
   reader = csv.reader(file)

   # r and c tell us where to grid the labels
   r = 0
   for col in reader:
      c = 0
      for row in col:
         # i've added some styling
         label = tkinter.Label(root, width = 10, height = 2, \
                               text = row, relief = tkinter.RIDGE)
         label.grid(row = r, column = c)
         c += 1
      r += 1


root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please rad this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506

Comment: a more specific help would be, create for each csv file a frame, pack them next to each other on your root window and then let your functions fill them.

Comment: Thank you Atlas I'll  read this tutorial :)

Comment: It is more like a guideline that will give you some essentally input. I started with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuoSKkSEhQg&list=PL6lxxT7IdTxGoHfouzEK-dFcwr_QClME_

Comment: If you like you could also use the Notebook widget of tkinter and its tabs instead of labels. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62979093/13629335

Comment: The youtube video link is very useful, thank you.